# How to find out the possible limits of the following iteration?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Consider the function $f(x)=\sqrt{2+x}$ for $x\geq2$ and the iteration $x_{n+1}$ = $f(x_n)$: $n\geq0$ for $x_o=1$.
What are the possible limits of the iteration?

1. $\sqrt{2+{\sqrt{2+{\sqrt{2+....}}}}}$
2. $-1$
3. $2$
4. $1$

If we consider ${x_n}$ a sequence then I find that it is a monotonically increasing sequence and bounded therefore convergent. Since all the entries are positive therefore option (2) can not be correct so I discarded this one. Also since all the entries are smaller than 2 implies that 2 is an upper bound I proved that this is a supremum so option (3) should be correct. I could not find the other possible limits and neither a way to find it. Please help!

Comment: $\sqrt{2+x}>\sqrt1$. So option 4 isn't correct. 1 is correct, let option 1$=x, x=\sqrt{2+x}$, that gives you option 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given , $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+x_{n}},n\ge 0 $ and $x_0=1$

Then , we proof by induction on $n$, $\sqrt{2}\lt x_{n} \le 2 $ .

For , $n=1, \sqrt{2}\lt x_{1}=\sqrt{3} \le 2 $ , so, the result is true.

Take , for $n=m$, the result is true i.e, $\sqrt{2}\lt x_{m} \le 2 $ .

Then, for $n=m+1$,$\sqrt{2}\lt x_{m} \le 2 \implies 2+\sqrt{2}\lt 2+x_{m} \le 4 \implies \sqrt{2}\lt \sqrt{2+x_{m}} \le 2 \implies \sqrt{2}\lt x_{m+1} \le 2 $

So, by induction on $n$, $\sqrt{2}\lt x_{n} \le 2 $ .

And, easily we can see the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is monotone increasing.

So, $\{x_n\}$ is monotone increasing and bounded.

So, clearly , $\{x_n\}$ is convergent i.e, $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n= K $

So, using limit to bothsides of $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+x_{n}}$,

We get, $K=\sqrt{2+K} \implies K^{2}-K-2=0 \implies (K-2)(K+1)=0 \implies K=2 $

($K\neq -1 $ , as, $\{x_n\}$ is sequence of positive reals.)

So, only option **(3)** is true.

Answer (score 1):

If the limit exists then:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n+1} = L
$$
Therefore:
$$
f(L) = L \implies L = \sqrt{2 + L} \implies L^2 - L - 2 = 0 \implies L \in \{-1,2\}
$$
As you said, the limit can't be negative as it's increasing and positive, so the only possible value is $L = 2$ (so option 4 is correct). Since the sequence converges and has a well-defined limit, we can write:
$$
\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \cdots}}} = 2
$$
So that option 1 makes sense as well.